# Ruby, Scrape page written entirely in JavaScript

Tags: ruby, screen-scraping, hpricot

I am playing with Ruby + Hpricot and building a simple scraper. I am able to work with other sites with no issues. But if a page is written entirely in JavaScript, can that be scraped?  <strike>but, google search results pages now seem to be entirely JavaScript based except a few internal links.</strike>

- Can pages written like this not be scraped by regular tools like Mechanize & Hpricot (My guess is they can't)
- Are they tools/gems available that may probably try to render the page(like a browser) and then collect data?

Thanks!

**Edit:** Thanks for your responses. I realize scraping google directly is not right, there is an API in place and that can be used. At the core of the question what I wanted to find-out really was if there is a page written entirely in javascript(including text and contents - could be obfuscated.) is there a gem that will try to Render the page in only text and then get its text contents?

Comment: Why would you try to scrape Google anyway, instead of using their API? (Hint: Google search results work just fine without JS. At least if you're using a text-based web browser.)

Comment: Google probably does not like you scraping their pages. You should use their API (and check what terms of service they have there)

Comment: @Chris : Thanks, I am checking with lynx what URL they use for regular text result pages.  @Thilo: I understand, I am just learning, so I'll probably only work with a couple of pages. Don't think they'll (mind|care).

Comment: I have an app that runs nightly on my laptop that searches Google and Yahoo, using their APIs. Don't bother scraping when you can get completely clean results the correct way.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a link for you that turns off instant loading.
http://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&tab=ww&complete=0

- Are they tools/gems available that may probably try to render the page(like a browser) and then collect data?

You can use [PhantomJS](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/) (C++) or [PyPhantomJS](http://dev.umaclan.com/projects/pyphantomjs/) (Python) for screen scraping if you want.

PyPhantomJS also has a really nice plugin system which the C++ one doesn't.

There's also a scraping library that someone just released for it.
[Google Groups post](http://groups.google.com/group/phantomjs/browse_thread/thread/8b4cf134b51ad283) | [GitHub address](https://github.com/nrabinowitz/pjscrape)

Note: As others have said though, Google doesn't want people to scrape their search results. I suggest complying with their Terms of Service.

Answer (score 2):

This is very, very important, so listen carefully:

> *Always* check 'robots.txt', first, and don't scrape if it tells you not to!

If you look at http://www.google.com/robots.txt, you will clearly see this line:

```
Disallow: /search
```

**Edit (based on asker's comments)**

Setting aside the 'robots.txt' issue for a moment, you are probably much better off learning using a simpler website, anyway. I'd suggest using a website or two that doesn't change often, so you can easily reproduce your results and verify that everything is working  as you expect it to.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [Google's TOS](http://www.google.com/accounts/TOS). Scraping their search results is not allowed. Use their search API.

Answer (score 0):

If you scrape Google, you absolutely must use proxies, at least 100+. Otherwise they'll easily ban your IP address.